# Calling inline functions in React Components - React Testing Library + Jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to test a component that has an inline function (event) which triggers another function, and those lines of codes are not covered when I test the coverage. I don't know how to deal with it.

**The Component**

```js
<Form
      {...props}
      submitButton={{
        label: i18n('next'),
        withArrow: true,
        disabled:
          (typeof props.businessFormData.tradeLicenseFileBase64 ===
            'undefined' ||
            props.businessFormData.tradeLicenseFileBase64.length === 0) &&
          (typeof props.businessFormData.companyLetterFileBase64 ===
            'undefined' ||
            props.businessFormData.companyLetterFileBase64.length === 0) &&
          (typeof props.businessFormData.emiratesIDFileBase64 === 'undefined' ||
            props.businessFormData.emiratesIDFileBase64.length === 0) &&
          (typeof props.businessFormData.passportFileBase64 === 'undefined' ||
            props.businessFormData.passportFileBase64.length === 0),
        onClick: () => props.requestClick(props),
      }}
      backButton={{
        label: i18n('back'),
        withArrow: true,
        alignIcon: 'start',
        uiType: 'secondary',
        onClick: () => props.backClick(props),
      }}
      cancelLink={{
        label: i18n(props.cancel),
        href: '/adc/importer-number-issuance/landing',
        target: '_self',
        disabled: false,
        tammHref: '/adc/importer-number-issuance/landing',
      }}
    >
```

**My Test**

```js
  test('onClick() -> requestClick should be called', async () => {
    const { getByText, getByLabelText } = render(
      <MemoryRouter>
        <ViewportProvider>
          <Viewport sm md lg xl>
            <TestDateInformation {...props} />
          </Viewport>
        </ViewportProvider>
      </MemoryRouter>,
    );
    await sleep();
    expect(getByText(/next/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
    fireEvent.click(getByText(/next/i));
    expect(props.requestClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

> I want to cover the inline function `requestClick`

Comment: What event triggers `requestClick `? Is it a user clicking on an element?

Comment: @johnnypeter yes a button click, which submits the form.

Comment: You can use `fireEvent.click` and use https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/fake-xhr-and-server/ to mock responses from server

Comment: I am using Jest not Sinon @johnnypeter